# Make object follow a path from a specific frame (not frame 0)

Tags: animation

I created a path (Shift + A: Curve -> Path) for an object to follow, and paired them together by selecting the path, the object, hitting Ctrl + P: Follow path). The object now follows the path, however, I would like this to happen from frame 50 and not from frame 0. I tried adjusting the evaluation time of the path, but blender won't let me add any keyframes to it - what's the usual approach to doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Ok, actually you should rather unparent and give your object a *Follow Path* constraint with the curve as *Target*.

Then, when you press *Animate Path*, it moves your object.

You can ether play with the constraint *Offset* value to move it the way you want. In your case keep it at 0 at Frame 50.

[image]

Or you can select the curve, go in the *Graph Editor*, unfold the *Bezier Curve* track on the left, select the *Evaluation Time*, display the N panel, select the *Modifiers* tab, close the *Generator*.

[image]

Now keep the curve selected, go in the *Properties* editor > *Data* > *Path Animation*, play with the *Evaluation Time* value and create some keyframes to make the object move along the curve. In your case, keep the *Evaluation Time* at 0 until frame 50.

[image]

Comment: Just what I needed :-) Thank you!